# Making a bluetooth connection on windows using C++ (getting error 10060)

Tags: c++, bluetooth, winsock

I'm trying to get 2 laptops with bluetooth to connect.
This is the code I'm using for making a server:

```
WSADATA wsd;
WSAStartup (MAKEWORD(1,0), &wsd);

SOCKET server_socket = socket(AF_BTH, SOCK_STREAM, BTHPROTO_RFCOMM);

SOCKADDR_BTH sa;
memset(&sa, 0, sizeof(sa));
sa.addressFamily = AF_BTH;
sa.port = 0 & 0xFF;

if(0 != bind(server_socket, (SOCKADDR *)&sa, sizeof(sa)))
{
    std::cout << "BIND ERROR: " << WSAGetLastError () << std::endl;
    closesocket(server_socket);
    return false;
}

if(0 != listen (server_socket, 5))
{
    std::cout << "LISTEN ERROR: " << WSAGetLastError () << std::endl;
    closesocket(server_socket);
    return false;
}

SOCKADDR_BTH sa2;
int size = sizeof(sa2);
SOCKET s2 = accept(server_socket, (SOCKADDR*)&sa2, &size);
if(s2 == INVALID_SOCKET)
{
    std::cout << "ACCEPT ERROR: " << WSAGetLastError () << std::endl;
    return false;
}
else
{
    std::cout << "Connected? " << WSAGetLastError () << std::endl;
}
```

and the following as a client:

```
WSADATA wsd;
WSAStartup (MAKEWORD(1,0), &wsd);

SOCKET client_socket = socket (AF_BTH, SOCK_STREAM, BTHPROTO_RFCOMM);

SOCKADDR_BTH sa;
memset (&sa, 0, sizeof(sa));
sa.addressFamily = AF_BTH;
sa.btAddr = (BTH_ADDR)d.getDeviceAddress();
sa.port = 0;
sa.serviceClassId = *d.getLpServiceClassId();

if(client_socket == INVALID_SOCKET)
{
    std::cout << "SOCKET ERROR: " << WSAGetLastError () << std::endl;
    return false;
}
if (0 != connect (client_socket, (SOCKADDR *)&sa, sizeof(sa))) 
{
    std::cout << "CONNECT ERROR: " << WSAGetLastError () << std::endl;
    return false;
}
else
{
    //std::cout << "CONNECT ERROR: " << WSAGetLastError () << std::endl;
    //Perform error handling.s
    send(client_socket, "ABC",3,0);
    closesocket (client_socket);
    return true;
}
```

Where "b" is the bluetooth device I give as argument the bluetoothdevice class has the following fields:

```
LPSOCKADDR local_address;
LPSOCKADDR device_address;
LPGUID lp_service_class_id;
```

This SHOULD work. But when I try to connect to the server, the server gets nothing and the client gives me error 10060.

This error means:

```
WSAETIMEDOUT 10060

The I/O timed out at the Bluetooth radio level (PAGE_TIMEOUT).
```

Is there anyone out here who has worked with the bluetooth stack on windows and knows where this error comes from?

Answer (score 0):

Have you registered your service with Bluetooth SDP? If no, I guess, you will not be able to connect using current approach in your client code. From MSDN:

`The bind function does not automatically advertise the server application using the Bluetooth SDP; applications must call the WSASetService function to be found by remote  Bluetooth applications.`

Also take a look to bluetooth documentation for `bind` and `connect` funcs:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa362901%28v=vs.85%29.aspx
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa362901%28v=vs.85%29.aspx

Another approach, as I understand, is that you can try to specify `port` explicitly at both server and client side. But it will be enough only for playground applications.

You can refer to http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa363058%28v=vs.85%29.aspx for more information on bluetooth usage.